# How can i change my sort function to both accept ascending order and descending order

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

i have an function, which looks like this:

```
 const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [sortType, setSortType] = useState("title");
  useEffect(() => {
    const sortArray = (type) => {
      const types = {
        title: "title",

        release_date: "release_date",
        charactersList: "charactersList",
      };
      const sortProperty = types[type];

      if (sortProperty === "charactersList") {
    
        const sorted = [...episodes].sort(
          (a, b) => a.charactersList.length - b.charactersList.length
        );

        setData(sorted);
      } else {
        const sorted = [...episodes].sort((a, b) =>
          ("" + a[sortProperty]).localeCompare("" + b[sortProperty])
        );
        setData(sorted);
      }
    };

    sortArray(sortType);
  }, [episodes, sortType]);
```

and the `select`:

```
<select defaultValue="Sort" onChange={(e) => setSortType(e.target.value)}>
        <option value="title">Alfabetycznie A-Z</option>
        <option value="release_date">wg. daty rosnąco</option>
        <option value="charactersList">wg. liczby postaci rosnąco</option>
 </select>
```

I was wondering,how can i change it, so i could choose an option of value="titleDESC" so that it would sort DESC?

Comment: Even if you sort by `charactersList`'s array length, you still do generic sort by `sortProperty` after.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sort function with an identified direction of sorting?

```
function sortTitle(a, b, d) {
  return a.localeCompare(b) * d;
}
```

Which you can call from your `array.sort()` like so:

```
array.sort((a,b) => sortTitle(a,b,-1))
```

see this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ubeyxc

If you make the call value of `d` to be contingent on `titleDESC` or `titleASC` you can use the same sorting function, just change the direction of the sorting.

```
const d = (sortProperty==='titleDESC') ? -1 : 1;
array.sort((a,b) => sortTitle(a,b,-1));
```